# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'seqA' was corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

i have windows 8 with vs2010, when i run this part of program this error shown:
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'seqA' was corrupted.
..............................................................................

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

    int main(){
int lenA = 0;
int lenB = 0;
FILE * fileA, * fileB;
char holder;
char seqA[10], seqB[10];

/*open first file*/
fileA=fopen("c:\\str1.fa", "r");

/*check to see if it opened okay*/
if(fileA == NULL) {
    perror ("Error opening 'str1.fa'\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


/*open second file*/
fileB = fopen("c:\\str2.fa", "r");

/*check to see if it opened okay*/
if(fileB == NULL) {
    perror ("Error opening 'str1.fa'\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/*measure file1 length*/
while(fgetc(fileA) != EOF) {
    holder = fgetc(fileA);
    seqA[lenA]=holder;
    lenA++;
}
lenA--;

fclose(fileA);

holder='0';

/*measure file2 length*/
while(fgetc(fileB) != EOF) {
    holder = fgetc(fileB);
    seqB[lenB]=holder;
    lenB++;
}
lenB--;

fclose(fileB);
```

link [picture](http://i1353.photobucket.com/albums/q671/mahdimb/ad_zps4ef6d8d6.jpg) of this error.

Comment: Unless your files are less than 10 bytes, you're writing past the end of the allocated arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method for reading file isn't safe. You have a variable which is a char [10] but what happend if your file have more than 10 character? You'll write in the memory using `seqA[10] = holder;` (for exemple) and by the way you'll overwrite the stack. I think that is the problem. A solution is to break after 10 character readed or use a dynamically allocated array and reallocate it when his size is reached.

Comment: this solution work, i use break and this error not shown:) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This: `seqB[lenA]=holder; lenA++;` will overflow unless your file is *very* short (10 characters or less (and likewise with `seqB` and `lenB`.

Answer (score 0):

You initialized seqA and SeqB to 10 chars. I think the file is bigger than that and you are corrupting the stack by writing outside the sequence array. Allocate more memory to the sequence.